# Google Search API - is it possible to do an IN query?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Using the Search API, is it possible to do an IN query? Where you can query for documents with a string parameter that is contained in an array of Strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Search API doesn't have an `IN` operator, but one can be emulated using the `OR` operator. For example, `pattern IN [word1, word2, word3]` and `pattern IN word_list`can be written as:

```
index.search('word1 OR word2 OR word3')
```

and, respectively:

```
index.search(' OR '.join(word_list))
```

Comment: How do you see this working with an array of potentially 1,000 - 5,000 "words" ? (array max). Do you think there would be a performance decrease in the lookup?

Comment: I didn't use the search API, but I'm guessing the performance would drop significantly. The `OR` ops are expensive, see [Turn disjunctions into conjunctions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/best_practices#turn_disjunctions_into_conjunctions). Maybe why `IN` isn't supported as such.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to query documents by their contents. 
There are several possibilities, you can find this example in [*Searching for documents by their contents*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/#Python_Searching_for_documents_by_their_contents):

```
def query_index():
    index = search.Index('products')
    query_string = 'product: piano OR price < 5000'

    results = index.search(query_string)

    for scored_document in results:
        print(scored_document)
```

You also can find more information about the [Query Class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/queryclass) and [its options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/queryoptionsclass) as well as more documentation about [how queries work](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/#Python_Queries), for example:

> The simplest query, sometimes called a "global search" is a string
>   that contains only field values. This search uses a string that
>   searches for documents that contain the words "rose" and "water":
>
> ```
> def simple_search(index):
>     index.search('rose water')
> ```

---

If the array of strings is too much big, using a categories array with string arrays could be an option to slightly reduce the cost. Some categories could be excluding which would help to reduce the query processing time. For example:

```
categories=[['animal','dog','cat','fish'],['positive','good','fine','great'],['negative','horrible',disgusting','awful'],['water recreation', 'relax','holidays','spa','beach','sea']]


def query_index():
    index = search.Index('products')
    for categ in categories:
        query_string = ' OR '.join(categ)
        results = index.search(query_string)
        if len(results)>0:
            print(categ[0])
            break

    for scored_document in results:
        print(scored_document)
```